# How to display calculated data in template

Tags: python, django

I need to get values from model fields, multiply and display the product in template.

For example, I have this code:

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    field1 = models.IntegerField()
    field2 = models.IntegerField()

    def multiply(self):
        return self.field1 * self.field2
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
   products = Product.objects.all()
   #something goes here?
   context = {
     'products': products
   }
   return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

**template**

```
{% for product in products %}
   {{ product.field1 }}
   {{ product.field2 }}
   here goes the value of field1/field2 {{ }}
{% endfor %}
```

How it's better to achieve this?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You have a `multiply` method on the model, why can't you have a `divide` method?

Comment: Sorry,my mistake. Just thought division as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a method on the model:

```
def divided_fields(self):
    return self.field1 / self.field2
```

And then im template:

```
{{ product.divided_fields }}
```

Another possibility would be to create a custom template tag or filter that handles division as there is no default tag or filter for such operations.

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [django-mathfilters](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mathfilters) for this.

```
{% load mathfilters %}

...

<h1>Basic math filters</h1>

<ul>
    <li>8 + 3 = {{ 8|add:3 }}</li>

    <li>13 - 17 = {{ 13|sub:17 }}</li>

    {% with answer=42 %}
    <li>42 * 0.5 = {{ answer|mul:0.5 }}</li>
    {% endwith %}

    {% with numerator=12 denominator=3 %}
    <li>12 / 3 = {{ numerator|div:denominator }}</li>
    {% endwith %}

    <li>|-13| = {{ -13|abs }}</li>
</ul>
```